# Modifying Twitter Embeddable Timelines

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Since Twitter API v1.1 went live you can no longer retrieve client side tweets so have to use their Embeddable Tweets.

I only want one tweet and only the text. The best I can do is shown in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXnJTlnTyhuWn6EGyNU9?p=preview).

I'm trying to work out how literally display the text.  I've tried using a promise but doesn't work as I dont think its implemented and jQuery executes too late.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this jsfiddle, maybe it can help.. http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/uMZ2c/

```
twitterFetcher.fetch('345634756626636800', function(tweets){
   // do with tweets whatever you want
});
```